# Unit test Website Application in Visual Studio 2010 vs Web Application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a project that is currently a "website" application but need to use Unit Testing. I notice on the majority of examples for unit testing seem to show only web applications.

- Would it be best to convert to web "application" first?
- What would be the pros and cons?
- What is the preferred way to develop and have unit test on a Visual
  Studio 2010 project(web applications or Website applications)?
- Do you see performance increase in both Testing/Development under Web App Projects?

One thing I noticed immediately is that in Web Application it simplifies testing because of the namespace formatting/generation. When you generate an auto-test using the wizard you get nice clean code.  (i.e. Employee class references the correct namespace...etc)

Ex:

```
Employee target = new Employee();
```

Whereas in website application when  you reference the code base for a class you get the following:

`Employee_Accessor target = new Employee_Accessor()`;

and this:

```
    [Shadowing("Employee")]
public class Employee_Accessor : BaseShadow, 
        INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected static PrivateType m_privateType; ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real question here is the difference between a Web Site Project vs a Web App Project.

If you read this detailed and clear explanation at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you will notice that MS recommends WAP over Web Sites and why.

So, to answer your questions:

- It is better to convert to a WAP first.
- Advantages - See the link
  above.
- Your 3rd question isn't clear to me. If you need a basic how to then [here it is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286656%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Corrected and added question.

Comment: The question on performance you have added is also answered in the MSDN link given.

Comment: Yeah I guess you are correct.  Thanks for that link.